# Renaming files by string from array?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an array of string pairs.
For example: `[["vendors", "users"], ["jobs", "venues"]]`

I have a list of files within a directory:

```
folder/
  -478_accounts
  -214_vendors
  -389_jobs
```

I need somehow to rename files with the second value from subarrays so it would look like this:

```
folder/
  -478_accounts
  -214_users
  -389_venues
```

How do I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
folder = %w| -478_accounts -214_vendors -389_jobs |
  #=> ["-478_accounts", "-214_vendors", "-389_jobs"] 
h = [["vendors", "users"], ["jobs", "venues"]].to_h
  #=> {"vendors"=>"users", "jobs"=>"venues"} 

r = Regexp.union(h.keys)
folder.each { |f| File.rename(f, f.sub(r,h)) if f =~ r }
```

I've used the form of [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) that employs a hash to make the substitution.

You might want to refine the regex to require the string to be replaced to follow an underscore and be at the end of the string.

```
r = /
    (?<=_)                  # match an underscore in a positive lookbehind
    #{Regexp.union(h.keys)} # match one of the keys of `h`
    \z                      # match end of string
    /x                      # free-spacing regex definition mode
#=> /
#   (?<=_)                  # match an underscore in a positive lookbehind
#   (?-mix:vendors|jobs) # match one of the keys of `h`
#   \z                      # match end of string
#   /x
```

You don't have to use a regex.

```
keys = h.keys
folder.each do |f|
  prefix, sep, suffix = f.partition('_')
  File.rename(f, prefix+sep+h[suffix]) if sep == '_' && keys.include?(suffix)
end
```